# How to make form dinamically after choose select

Tags: codeigniter, select

i'd some problem regarding make some text-form which connected with selected-form. My problem like this, i want to make dynamic from which correlated with select-option,
if i choose in select option 1 Form, in the below will show 1 text-form, if select 2 form, it will show 2 text-form, if i choose 3, show 3 text-form, etc..

i already tried this code :

```
<label class="control-label" for="nama_hukuman">Config</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <select data-placeholder="Choose Modulation..." class="chzn-select1" style="width:300px;" tabindex="2" name="modul" id="combo" onChange="check();">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1+0" <?php if($modul == '1+0'){echo "selected";} ?> >1+0</option>
                <option value="2+0" <?php if($modul == '2+0'){echo "selected";} ?> >2+0</option>
                <option value="3+0" <?php if($modul == '3+0'){echo "selected";} ?> >3+0</option>
                <option value="4+0" <?php if($modul == '4+0'){echo "selected";} ?> >4+0</option>
                <option value="1+1SD" <?php if($modul == '1+1SD'){echo "selected";} ?> >1+1SD</option>
                <option value="2+2SD" <?php if($modul == '2+2SD'){echo "selected";} ?> >2+2SD</option>
                <option value="4+4SD" <?php if($modul == '4+4SD'){echo "selected";} ?> >4+4SD</option>
              </select>

              <input type="text" class="span" name="sub_sow" value="<?php echo $sub_sow; ?>" style="width:300px;visibility:hidden" id ="dummyText1" visible="false" placeholder="Detail SOW..">
              <input type="text" class="span" name="sub_sow" value="<?php echo $sub_sow; ?>" style="width:300px;visibility:hidden" id ="dummyText2" visible="false" placeholder="Detail SOW..">
            </div>
```

and for js :

```
<script>
    function check() {
    var el = document.getElementById("combo");
    var str = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;
    if(str == "1+0") {
            document.getElementById('dummyText1').style.visibility='visible';
    }else {
            document.getElementById('dummyText2').style.visibility='visible';
    }   
</script>
```

my code in above can't work
is there any reference for me?
i search i google but i don't know the keyword for what i mean,

thanks for your advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's working change value as per your need
this is your js code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

    function check() {
    var str=$('#combo').val();
    if(str == "1+0") {
            $('#dummyText1').show();
            $('#dummyText2').hide();
    }else {
            $('#dummyText1').hide();
            $('#dummyText2').show();
    }  
    }

</script>
```

Html Code

```
<label class="control-label" for="nama_hukuman">Config</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <select data-placeholder="Choose Modulation..." class="chzn-select1" style="width:300px;" tabindex="2" name="modul" id="combo" onChange="check()">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1+0" <?php if($modul == '1+0'){echo "selected";} ?> >1+0</option>
                <option value="2+0" <?php if($modul == '2+0'){echo "selected";} ?> >2+0</option>
                <option value="3+0" <?php if($modul == '3+0'){echo "selected";} ?> >3+0</option>
                <option value="4+0" <?php if($modul == '4+0'){echo "selected";} ?> >4+0</option>
                <option value="1+1SD" <?php if($modul == '1+1SD'){echo "selected";} ?> >1+1SD</option>
                <option value="2+2SD" <?php if($modul == '2+2SD'){echo "selected";} ?> >2+2SD</option>
                <option value="4+4SD" <?php if($modul == '4+4SD'){echo "selected";} ?> >4+4SD</option>
              </select>

              <input type="text" class="span" name="sub_sow" value="<?php echo $sub_sow1; ?>" style="width:300px;display:none" id ="dummyText1" visible="false" placeholder="Detail SOW..">
              <input type="text" class="span" name="sub_sow" value="<?php echo $sub_sow2; ?>" style="width:300px;display:none" id ="dummyText2" visible="false" placeholder="Detail SOW..">
            </div>
```

Comment: thanks, it's work, but i found some problem, the hidden form make space with next form, how to set hidden so don't have any space with next form? you can see in this capture http://prntscr.com/fkt3vh

Comment: take hidden form in division and set divison `style="display:none;"`

Comment: i just added it, it didn't work, my header div :
<div class="controls" style="display:none;">